# android:textAllCaps not working in Jelly Bean for ActionBar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I have a styled actionbar like this:

```
<style name="MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/action_bar_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

color and style work but allCaps does not on JB (4.2.2) it works on ICS and on JB 4.1, it does not work on older versions, but that's documented.

Anyone got this issue?

I cannot fix this in code as theses are the Activity titles, set in the manifest.

I use actionbarsherlock so maybe the problem is there?

Comment: maybe some code will be helpful to investigate the problem.

Comment: You want to style action bar title right?

Comment: I'm having same problem: 4.1.2 works, 4.3 doesn't... I'll get back to you as soon as I have an answer (soon).